# How do we use the merge statement inside Incremental model for SCD 1 Implementation

Tags: dbt

I am trying to implement the scd1 in Data Build Tools using the Merge query. But I am not getting the exact way to write this query in Incremental model.

Can anyone show where we have to write the merge query.

```
{{
    config(
        materialized='incremental'
    )
}}

<MERGE QUERY HERE> 

{% if is_incremental() %}
where last_modified_date > '2020-07-11'
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need to write the merge statement, dbt will take care of that for you. You should write a query that will return the records you want to upsert. You can then check the log for the merge query dbt generates.

Also check out the dbt docs on configuring incremental models: https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/configuring-incremental-models#what-is-an-incremental_strategy

Comment: But how will I define the additional statement in “when matched” clause of merge. As in dbt the upsert will happen if any of the column is changed. But I need to perform update only when few columns are changed. Is there a work around to specify additional conditional statements in when matched clause.

Comment: @VipendraSingh I'd recommend reviewing this article as well as the in-depth comments: 
https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/on-the-limits-of-incrementality/303/2.
I think you may need to specify your desired "update" keys as `unique_key` elements as in Claus' comment. Not sure how to make that a multiple value - sorry.